# Why is Java function Supplier allowing to execute private methods from another class?

Tags: java, oop

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class MethodReference {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MethodHolder mh = new MethodHolder();
        System.out.println(mh.methodMap.get(1).get());
        System.out.println(mh.methodMap.get(2).get());
        System.out.println(mh.methodMap.get(3).get());
        System.out.println(mh.methodMap.get(4).get());
    }
}

class MethodHolder {
    public Map<Integer, Supplier<String>> methodMap = new HashMap<>();
    private int count = 1;

    public MethodHolder() {
        methodMap.put(1, this::method1);
        methodMap.put(2, this::method2);
        methodMap.put(3, this::method3);
        methodMap.put(4, this::method4);
    }

    public String method1() {
        return "public method1 - " + (++count);
    }

    protected String method2() {
            return "protected method2 - " + (++count);
    }

    String method3() {
                return "default method3 - " + (++count);
    }

    private String method4() {
                return "private method4 - " + (++count);
    }
}
```

Doesn't this break the method access specifier contract?

We can access private using Reflection but is Supplier too using reflection? What is the rationale behind this?

Comment: Where you reference the methods, they are all accessible.

Comment: Why are method access specifier contracts not enforced in reference?

Comment: They are. Again, from where the methods are used, they are accessible (see my answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not "break the method access specifier contract" because access modifiers control where you can access things. The *access* to `method2` and `method4` occurs *inside* `MethodHolder` - the same class where they are declared.

```
// this happens in the MethodHolder class:
methodMap.put(1, this::method1);
methodMap.put(2, this::method2);
methodMap.put(3, this::method3);
methodMap.put(4, this::method4);
```

So nothing is wrong here.

It does not matter where you call `get`. After all, when you call `get`, you are accessing the method [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Supplier.html#get()), which is a public method declared in `Supplier`, so you are allowed to access it from anywhere.

The fact that calling `get` *actually* causes the method `method4` in your `MethodHolder` to be executed, is none of the business of access modifiers. That is an implementation detail.

And no, method references are not implemented with reflection. They are implemented with an `invokedynamic` instruction - a class implementing the `Supplier` interface is dynamically created at runtime and instantiated, when the method reference expression is evaluated.

---

Basically, claiming that this "breaks the method access specifier contract" is like saying that, since calling `publicMethod` (see below) from outside `MyClass` causes `privateMethod` to be executed, allowing public methods to call private methods also "breaks the method access specifier contract"

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyClass().publicMethod(); // I can cause privateMethod to be executed here!
        // Does this "break access specifier contract"? No!
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    public void publicMethod() { privateMethod(); }
    private void privateMethod() {}
}
```

In the same way that calling `privateMethod` is just an implementation detail of `publicMethod` in the above example, Your `method4` is just an implementation of `get`, albeit in a less obvious way, because it is a method reference.

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
    methodMap.put(4, this::method4);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
    methodMap.put(4, new Supplier<String>() {
        @Override
        public String get() {
            return MethodHolder.this.method4();
        }
    });
```

This code is in the `MethodHolder` class, so it can use any method of this class, including `private` ones.

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't this break the method access specifier contract?

No, it does not because you are calling method by using `methodMap`.

`methodMap` is `public`, however, it can call all methods and properties of class with *any* access modifier where it is placed.

It is not usual way to use methods of class, but you can.

Usually, mapping is used when [Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) can be applied. Let me show an example via C#:

```
public enum SubscriptionType 
{
    WebSocket, Grpc
}


public class PublisherFactory
{
    private Dictionary<SubscriptionType, Publisher> _pubisherByType = 
        new Dictionary<SubscriptionType, Publisher>()
    {
        { SubscriptionType.WebSocket, new  WebSocketPublisher () },
        { SubscriptionType.Grpc, new GrpcPublisher () },
    };

    public Publisher GetInstanceByType(SubscriptionType courtType) => 
        _pubisherByType[courtType];
}
```